# kdeinit5 fails constantly with Fedora 29

Tags: linux, fedora, crash, kde

I'm using Fedora 29 + KDE 5.14.5 + KDE Framework 5.59.0 + QT 5.11.3. For last couple days I'm getting lot of kdeinit5 crashes. I have no idea what is causing that crashes, there is no specific action that leads to fail. In logs I get such info:

```
localhost.localdomain plasmashell[2011]: QQuickItem::stackAfter: Cannot stack StatusNotifierItem_QMLTYPE_372(0x557f6d64dc00, parent=0x557f688f>
aug 27 15:43:35 localhost.localdomain plasmashell[2011]: file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationDelegate.qml:>
aug 27 15:43:35 localhost.localdomain systemd-coredump[5172]: Process 3301 (file.so) of user 1000 dumped core.

                                                                 Stack trace of thread 3301:
                                                                 #0  0x00007f8e509828b5 _ZN6QMutex4lockEv (libQt5Core.so.5)
                                                                 #1  0x00007f8e50b76186 _ZN10QTextCodec14codecForLocaleEv (libQt5Core.so.5)
                                                                 #2  0x00007f8e50a00569 _ZN7QString20fromLocal8Bit_helperEPKci (libQt5Core.so.5)
                                                                 #3  0x00007f8e50ad67b8 _ZN14QStandardPaths16writableLocationENS_16StandardLocationE (libQt5Co>
                                                                 #4  0x00007f8e51c35881 n/a (libKF5Crash.so.5)
                                                                 #5  0x00007f8e51c36362 n/a (libKF5Crash.so.5)
                                                                 #6  0x00007f8e51c36815 _ZN6KCrash19defaultCrashHandlerEi (libKF5Crash.so.5)
                                                                 #7  0x00007f8e50406600 .annobin_sigaction.c (libc.so.6)
aug 27 15:43:35 localhost.localdomain systemd-coredump[5173]: Process 3991 (file.so) of user 1000 dumped core.

                                                                 Stack trace of thread 3991:
                                                                 #0  0x00007f8e509828b5 _ZN6QMutex4lockEv (libQt5Core.so.5)
                                                                 #1  0x00007f8e50b76186 _ZN10QTextCodec14codecForLocaleEv (libQt5Core.so.5)
                                                                 #2  0x00007f8e50a00569 _ZN7QString20fromLocal8Bit_helperEPKci (libQt5Core.so.5)
                                                                 #3  0x00007f8e50ad67b8 _ZN14QStandardPaths16writableLocationENS_16StandardLocationE (libQt5Co>
                                                                 #4  0x00007f8e51c35881 n/a (libKF5Crash.so.5)
                                                                 #5  0x00007f8e51c36362 n/a (libKF5Crash.so.5)
                                                                 #6  0x00007f8e51c36815 _ZN6KCrash19defaultCrashHandlerEi (libKF5Crash.so.5)
                                                                 #7  0x00007f8e50406600 .annobin_sigaction.c (libc.so.6)
aug 27 15:43:35 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-cor>
aug 27 15:43:35 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-cor>
aug 27 15:43:36 localhost.localdomain kwin_x11[1996]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 42177, resource id: 123731979, major cod>
aug 27 15:43:37 localhost.localdomain abrt-server[5210]: Deleting problem directory ccpp-2019-08-27-15:43:35.946209-3301 (dup of ccpp-2019-08-26-17:08:51.2832>
aug 27 15:43:37 localhost.localdomain abrt-server[5210]: Lock file '.lock' is locked by process 2388
aug 27 15:43:38 localhost.localdomain abrt-notification[5253]: Process 4388 (kdeinit5) crashed in QMutex::lock()()
aug 27 15:43:40 localhost.localdomain abrt-server[5211]: Deleting problem directory ccpp-2019-08-27-15:43:35.962232-3991 (dup of ccpp-2019-08-26-17:08:51.2832>
aug 27 15:43:40 localhost.localdomain abrt-notification[5298]: Process 4388 (kdeinit5) crashed in QMutex::lock()()
```

I have checked all other SO topic with the same issue and there is no definite answer. Can anybody point me to a problem that is causing all that crashes?

**EDIT 1**
Looks like there are related lines in xsessions-errors:

```
AppIconMgr::systemDesktopName log Desktop Name: /usr/share/xsessions/plasma 
Error: Send error, 22 Invalid argument
Error: Send error, 22 Invalid argument
Error: Send error, 22 Invalid argument
KCrash: Application 'kdeinit5' crashing...
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
CSBConfUI::OnConfStatusChanged  UI_CMD_SHARE_READYqrc:/qml/JoinAudio.qml:71: TypeError: Cannot read property of null
qrc:/qml/JoinAudio.qml:72: TypeError: Cannot read property of null
[4424:4424:0827/185838.722928:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
KCrash: Application 'kdeinit5' crashing...
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
KCrash: Application 'kdeinit5' crashing...
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
KCrash: Application 'kdeinit5' crashing...
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
KCrash: Application 'kdeinit5' crashing...
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
qrc:/qml/AttendeeItemDelegate.qml:26: TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemType' of undefined
qrc:/qml/AttendeeItemDelegate.qml:360: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isItemHovered' of undefined
qrc:/qml/AttendeeItemDelegate.qml:26: TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemType' of undefined
qrc:/qml/AttendeeItemDelegate.qml:360: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isItemHovered' of undefined
qrc:/qml/AttendeeItemDelegate.qml:26: TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemType' of undefined
qrc:/qml/AttendeeItemDelegate.qml:360: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isItemHovered' of undefined
qrc:/qml/AttendeeItemDelegate.qml:26: TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemType' of undefined
qrc:/qml/AttendeeItemDelegate.qml:360: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isItemHovered' of undefined
qrc:/qml/AttendeeItemDelegate.qml:26: TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemType' of undefined
qrc:/qml/AttendeeItemDelegate.qml:360: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isItemHovered' of undefined
qrc:/qml/AttendeeItemDelegate.qml:26: TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemType' of undefined
qrc:/qml/AttendeeItemDelegate.qml:360: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isItemHovered' of undefined
qrc:/qml/AttendeeItemDelegate.qml:26: TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemType' of undefined
qrc:/qml/AttendeeItemDelegate.qml:360: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isItemHovered' of undefined
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but you are not alone. I just started experiencing this in the past few days and found your post while trying to look for an answer. It must be the result of a recent update.

Comment: @ws_e_c421, make sense. But in my case, the button "Report the bug" is not enabled, cause there is no stacktrace. Do you have a chance to report this issue?

Comment: Hitting same thing w/o crash report too. Can you edit your question and include results from `~/.xsession-errors` (not sure what is relevant)? One sticks out: `Cannot load library libkdeinit5_kdeinit5`, but that library doesn't seem to exist (`dnf provides "/*/*kdeinit5*" | cut -d : -f 2 | /bin/grep "\.so" | uniq | sort`).  Also seems to be some HTTP stuff possibly related, can't figure out what causes this crash though.  [Possibly related thread](https://github.com/pbek/QOwnNotes/issues/258#issuecomment-234928454), but I don't know what that user is changing that they said fixed things.

Comment: @svenevs I have added related line from xsessions-error, but there is no info bout libkdeinit5_kdeinit5 in my case.

Comment: Hmmm. So by process of elimination, since you have the error but no message about that I think it's unrelated.  Sometimes my desktop icons get crazy with little speckled images and I `nohup kquitapp5 plasmashell &> /dev/null & nohup kstart5 plasmashell &> /dev/null &`.  I think it's related to the NVIDIA drivers.  I suspect this error gets triggered whenever that happens, kind of hard to reproduce :(  Will post back if I find anything new

Comment: @svenevs looks like it is not about drivers. Take a look at a new answer.

Comment: @TrentP's answer will soon be the only relevant one -- update the `kf5-kio-core` package to the `-2` version. It should also be mentioned somewhere here that Fedora 29 is almost end of life and another solution is to update to Fedora 30.

Answer (score 4):

I was encountering the exact same issue on a fresh Fedora 29 installation and was baffled. As @snegovik noted, crash reliably occurs when closing dolphin, and that was driving me insane. The solution as per snegovik's answer is to downgrade, but the repos already removed the older `kf5-*` packages.

However, there is still hope. Fedora apparently has some older packages on the Koji build system, and kf5-*-5.58.0-1 packages are available.

https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1268224

There's quite a few packages so I extracted the URLs from the web source. Here's the command I ran:

```bsh
sudo dnf install \
    https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/noarch/kf5-kio-doc-5.58.0-1.fc29.noarch.rpm \
    https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/x86_64/kf5-kio-5.58.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm \
    https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/x86_64/kf5-kio-core-5.58.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm \
    https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/x86_64/kf5-kio-core-libs-5.58.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm \
    https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/x86_64/kf5-kio-devel-5.58.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm \
    https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/x86_64/kf5-kio-file-widgets-5.58.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm \
    https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/x86_64/kf5-kio-gui-5.58.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm \
    https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/x86_64/kf5-kio-ntlm-5.58.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm \
    https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/x86_64/kf5-kio-widgets-5.58.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm \
    https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/x86_64/kf5-kio-widgets-libs-5.58.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm \
    https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/x86_64/kf5-kio-core-debuginfo-5.58.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm \
    https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/x86_64/kf5-kio-debuginfo-5.58.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm \
    https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/x86_64/kf5-kio-debugsource-5.58.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm \
    https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/x86_64/kf5-kio-devel-debuginfo-5.58.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm \
    https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/x86_64/kf5-kio-gui-debuginfo-5.58.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm \
    https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/x86_64/kf5-kio-ntlm-debuginfo-5.58.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm
```

Last step is to keep the packages back to prevent accidentally upgrading back to 5.59.0-1. I added this to `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`:

```
excludepkgs=kf5-kio kf5-*-*
```

Note I used `kf5-*-*` and not `kf5-*` because there's some other packages like `kf5-kdbusaddons.x86_64` that seem fine if they're upgraded.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry - can not comment yet - had to use answer section.
Hit the same problem on Fedora 29 with KDE5.
Getting this error mostly right after I close dolphin:

> We are sorry, kdeinit5 closed unexpectedly.
>   You cannot report this error, because kdeinit5 does not provide a bug report address.

This is a result of kf5-* updates.
Checked another system with kf5-* version 5.58.0-1 and did

```
dnf update -x kf5-*
```

Result - NO ERRORS.
Updating kf5-* version 5.58.0-1 to kf5-* version 5.59.0-1:

```
dnf update
```

Result - ERRORS.

Did some more digging:

1. Removed NVIDIA drivers from the system - running on nouveau only.
   Errors still persist.
2. Used another system with AMD RX580 video - same result: Errors still persist.
3. Did: `dnf reinstall kf5-*-` same result: Errors still persist.

Conclusion - this error does NOT relate to any particular video driver.
This error relates to latest kf5-* version 5.59.0-1 update ONLY.
Unfortunately you can not downgrade to kf5-* version 5.58.0-1 - as it is already removed from servers.

**EDIT1 September 03 2019:**

I did a bit more digging over the weekend.
All latest versions of kf5-kio starting from 5.59.0 have that bug.
Checked also 5.60.0 and 5.61.0

Thank you rayting for providing a link to the old (kf5-*5.58.0*) source - it saved me!

Here is what I did:
I think it will break all warranties from Fedora (if you have any) but this works for me.
Please do not blame me if it breaks your system :-)

1. List all application groups installed on your system - including hidden ones (as root or use sudo if you have it configured):

```
   dnf group list --hidden
   sudo dnf group list --hidden
```

2. Install all required development packages (may take a while) and make sure everything is up to date:
   Warning: May add to your system significant amount of used space - make sure you have enough storage.

```
   dnf -y group install "C Development Tools and Libraries" "KDE Software Development" "KDE Frameworks 5 Software Development" "RPM Development Tools"
   sudo dnf -y group install "C Development Tools and Libraries" "KDE Software Development" "KDE Frameworks 5 Software Development" "RPM Development Tools"

   dnf update
   sudo dnf update
```

3. Open konsole as user and download source for kf5-kio-5.58.0-1:

```
   wget https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kf5-kio/5.58.0/1.fc29/src/kf5-kio-5.58.0-1.fc29.src.rpm
```

4. Install source rpm:

```
   rpm -Uvh kf5-kio-5.58.0-1.fc29.src.rpm
```

5. Change to a SOURCES directory that was created:

```
   cd ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES
```

6. Extract archive for kf5-kio:

```
   tar -xf kio-5.58.0.tar.xz
```

7. Move extracted directory to kio-5.59.0 (this is cheating! :-)

```
   mv kio-5.58.0 kio-5.59.0
```

8. Compress this directory:

```
   tar -cJf kio-5.59.0.tar.xz kio-5.59.0
```

9. Modify .spec file to display a "NEW" version and release:

```
   sed -i -e "s/Version: 5.58.0/Version: 5.59.0/g" ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/kf5-kio.spec
   sed -i -e "s/Release: 1%{?dist}/Release: 33%{?dist}/g" ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/kf5-kio.spec
```

10. Build a new srcrpm:

```
   rpmbuild --bs ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/kf5-kio.spec
```

11. Rebuild src rpm (will take 5-10 minutes depending on your hardware):

```
   rpmbuild --rebuild ~/rpmbuild/SRPMS/kf5-kio-5.59.0-33.fc29.src.rpm
```

12. It will also build "debugsource" and "debuginfo" packages (can someone direct me on how to permanently disable that on Fedora?):
    Remove these and update your kf5:

```
    rm -f ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/*/*debug*
    ls -las ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/*/*
    su
    dnf update %(user_home)/rpmbuild/RPMS/*/*
```

13. After that close and reopen Dolphin - then try to close it again - you should have no more crashes.

Conclusion: There was a change in kf5-kio package between version 5.58.0 and 5.59.0 that is still persists in versions 5.60.0 and 5.61.0 that is causing kdeinit5 to crash on Dolphin close.
            Only after fixing this bug (on KDE part) and back-porting that fix to kf5 versions 5.59.0, 5.60.0 and 5.61.0 the crash will not be produced anymore.

Comment: Great clarification! Thanks Dmitriy!

Comment: I can confirm that it reliably happens after closing dolphin as well.  Thank you for going through all that find out for sure about graphics drivers, that's very helpful in eliminating a lot of suspects :)  Good news: I think you can now comment since we've up-voted you! <3

Comment: Yes I can! :-) Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Worthwelle, for formatting my answer! I will try to do it myself this time.

Answer (score 1):

This bug appears to be fixed by the [this commit](https://cgit.kde.org/kio.git/commit/?id=2c379fecccbf5e2c0b20a93c843c009f2f597318) to KDE:

> Summary: All QTextCodec are deleted by QCoreGlobalData on exit, so
>   they must be allocated on the heap. Before Qt 5.12, it is even not
>   allowed to delete them.
>
> BUG: 408797

An update to Fedora 29 has been submitted, [FEDORA-2019-01dfc11f76](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2019-01dfc11f76)

By following that link above, then builds, one can get to the koji build of the kf5-kio-5.90.0-2 package for that pending update: https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1392448

From there it is possible to download the RPMs and install them. 
 I've found that only `kf5-kio-core-5.59.0-2.fc29.x86_64.rpm` need be installed to fix this issue, as it contains the `file.so` library with the bug.  It can be installed individually, without the other RPMs from the build, via `sudo rpm -Uvh kf5-kio-core-5.59.0-2.fc29.x86_64.rpm --nodeps`.

Force installing and ignoring dependencies like this is not generally a good idea, but the -2 build here only fixes this bug from the -1 build so it's probably safe, and I've seen no problems so far.  And Fedora 29 should get the update released sooner or later, at which point dnf will update everything.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers explain with precision what the problem is and how to build an older version while we wait for a fix.  I also found [a detailed thread here](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/kde@lists.fedoraproject.org/thread/LL4BLR2SNF33BQS6XKQIXYNNHX34SWGU) for which one of the users suggests setting the `KDE_DEBUG=1` environment variable.

I went that route since it was fast but forgot to post back, so for solidarity if you add something like this to your shell startup login file (e.g., `~/.bash_profile` not `~/.bashrc`):

```
export KDE_DEBUG=1
```

then this will prevent you from getting this, but also ANY OTHER crash reports.  The only noticeable impact this had on my setup was that `KDE_DEBUG` doesn't seem to play well with high DPI screens, so I used System Settings to scale the monitor up.

Doing this comes with other consequences I'm sure, but since I was editing my `~/.bash_profile` and realized I never directed this "trick" here, thought I would post back...

Comment: export KDE_DEBUG=1 - does not help in my case. I still get notification about crashes.

Comment: Did you logout and relogin or restart? It needs to be set when logging in (as compared to putting in `~/.bashrc` which is loaded with every new terminal you spawn). Locking / unlocking is not sufficient, changes to `~/.bash_profile` require you to fully logout and back in. Sorry if you already know this!  So it has to be in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` because those get sourced when KDE is getting loaded up (very vague / incomplete description, but that's basically how it works).